# Neural network to tag multiple textual topics in a single document

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, topic-models

I want to use a neural network to do some topic analysis in a textual corpus. I have used neural networks before where there is a clear decision boundary between the category to which some observation belongs. However, in topic modeling, a single document can have multiple topics present simultaneously.

So I want to know if I can train a neural network model to associate multiple topics to each document in the corpus. I suppose this could be some sort of vector that just indicates the probability of some topic existing in that document>

I was looking around for any papers on this topic, so if there are any citations that you want to pass along, that would help too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use neural networks in this way - it's an example of multi-label learning. There are many approaches, but one is to create binary target vectors indicating which labels should be applied to each document. Or a vector of probabilities as you suggest.

There are plenty of papers on multilabel learning, with or without neural nets - one recent review is [Zhang & Zhou 2014](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6471714).

Comment: Wow, this article was a great resource. Thanks so much for the insight.